# Send Email to user when case attachment is empty

Tags: trigger, email, process-builder

My requirement is to send user an email after 10 mins, after he creates a case. Once the case is created and saved, **if there is no case attachment,the user should be sent an email.**

I am planning to do this via a process builder and call the apex method
[image]  using @InvocableMethod.

I need help with the apex method code

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please post code snippets of your implementation and try to explain what issue are facing?

Comment: This is my existing code where I am throwing a validation when user tries to save a record without an attachment. I now want to send email to user now.

Comment: @AshishSharma i have posted my code below. The code throws a validation when a user tries to save a case with an attachment. I want to send an email as a reminder to add attachment

Comment: Can you please paste your code in question rather than adding an answer for the same?

Comment: If you are trying to do it after 10 mins from Case created time, then you should not use addError for any validation because scheduled actions will run after sometime. Case would already be created by that time. For sending an email it should be fine to call it from a scheduled action in process builder

Comment: (1) [Time-based actions in minutes](https://sftipshack.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/the-5-minute-time-based-workflow-or-15-minute-or-30-minute/) ; (2) Use trigger to update count of attachments on Case.  No invocable apex should be needed

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public static void WDMSAttachmentValidator(List<Case> newList){ 
                List<RecordType>recId=[select id from recordtype where Name='WDMS Customer Admin' LIMIT 1];
         List<Attachment> listA = new List<Attachment>();

          set<id> caseIds=new set<id>();
                for(Case c:newList) {
                System.debug('gargi--'+c.Sub_Type__c );

                if(c.recordtypeId == recId.get(0).id && ((c.Sub_Type__c == 'Process Contract') || (c.Sub_Type__c == 'Process Recontract') || (c.Sub_Type__c == 'Process Trial')||(c.Sub_Type__c == 'Request Cancel Quote')|| (c.Sub_Type__c == 'Vendor Form')||(c.Sub_Type__c == 'DSA Account/contact change'))){
                                       caseIds.add(c.id);
                }
        if(!caseIds.isEmpty()){
            listA =[SELECT Id,ParentId From Attachment WHERE ParentId IN: caseIds AND Parent.Type = 'Case'];

        if(listA.isEmpty()){
            for(case item:newList){
            if(c.Sub_Type__c != 'DSA Account/contact change'){
                item.addError('Cannot save without attachment or when sub-type is '+c.Sub_Type__c );
            }else{
                item.addError('Cannot save without attachment or when sub-type is DSA Change');
            }
        }
        }
        }

   }
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but rather additional information for your question. You should [edit your original question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/260980/edit) to add this information.